# Take several 'userID's out of WHERE statement and putting into variable

Tags: sql, variables

I have the following query that works just fine.

```
SELECT ui.userID, 
    ui.lockedInd, 
    ui.lockedBy, 
    ui.lockedReason, 
    ui.updatedDtTm,
    ui.updatedBy,
    ua.password,
    ua.updatedDtTm,
    ua.updatedBy 
FROM userInfo ui 
JOIN userAuthentication ua 
    ON ui.userinfoseqid = ua.userinfoseqid
WHERE ui.userID IN (
    'userOne',
    'userTwo'
)
```

I would like to put the user names into a variable declared at the top. I'm slightly confused how to create the variable and add to it as I've always only done variables with one value. Sudo code below

```
DECLARE @userIDs
SET @userIDs = "'userOne', 'userTwo'"

SELECT ui.userID, 
    ui.lockedInd, 
    ui.lockedBy, 
    ui.lockedReason, 
    ui.updatedDtTm,
    ui.updatedBy,
    ua.password,
    ua.updatedDtTm,
    ua.updatedBy 
FROM userInfo ui 
JOIN userAuthentication ua 
    ON ui.userinfoseqid = ua.userinfoseqid
WHERE ui.userID = @userIDs
```

Comment: What's the motivation behind creating the variable?

Comment: The .sql file that this is a part of uses the exact same WHERE clause in two select statements and an update statement. So if a userID changes, I'd have to change it 3 locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary table, there is more info: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

For example, create a table variable:

```
DECLARE @UserIDs TABLE (ID nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @UserIDs VALUES ('userOne'), ('userTwo')

SELECT ui.userID
FROM userInfo ui 
JOIN userAuthentication ua 
    ON ui.userinfoseqid = ua.userinfoseqid
WHERE ui.userID IN (SELECT ID FROM @UserIDs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use of table variables should work for you.

```
DECLARE @UserIDS TABLE 
(
    UserId VARCHAR(40)
)

INSERT INTO @UserIDS
(
UserId
)
SELECT 'UserOne'
UNION ALL SELECT 'UserTwo'
UNION ALL SELECT 'UserThree'

SELECT ui.userID, 
    ui.lockedInd, 
    ui.lockedBy, 
    ui.lockedReason, 
    ui.updatedDtTm,
    ui.updatedBy,
    ua.password,
    ua.updatedDtTm,
    ua.updatedBy 
FROM userInfo ui 
JOIN userAuthentication ua 
    ON ui.userinfoseqid = ua.userinfoseqid
WHERE ui.userID IN @UserIDS
```